# How to disable d3plus timeline time formating?

Tags: d3.js, time, timeline, autoformatting, d3plus

I have created a bar chart using d3plus. In the code I have created timeline using the following lines:

```
    .time({
         "value": "__TIME__"
     )
   .timeline({
        "align":"center",
        "value":true})
```

This is showing a timeline in my chart like below:[image]

In my data, the **__TIME__** variable contains only numbers(1,2,3,4..). But the timeline converted it into months. I just want plain numbers (1,2,3,4....) instead of auto formatting of the time.

Is it possible to disable the auto formatting for the timeline?
Here is the sample jsfiddle:

```js
var data = [{
  "day": 0,
  "name": "alpha",
  "value": 15
}, {
  "day": 1,
  "name": "alpha",
  "value": 34
}, {
  "day": 0,
  "name": "alpha2",
  "value": 17
}, {
  "day": 1,
  "name": "alpha2",
  "value": 65
}, {
  "day": 1,
  "name": "beta",
  "value": 10
}, {
  "day": 1,
  "name": "beta",
  "value": 10
}, {
  "day": 0,
  "name": "beta2",
  "value": 40
}, {
  "day": 1,
  "name": "beta2",
  "value": 38
}, {
  "day": 0,
  "name": "gamma",
  "value": 5
}, {
  "day": 1,
  "name": "gamma",
  "value": 10
}, {
  "day": 0,
  "name": "gamma2",
  "value": 20
}, {
  "day": 1,
  "name": "gamma2",
  "value": 34
}, {
  "day": 0,
  "name": "delta",
  "value": 50
}, {
  "day": 2,
  "name": "delta",
  "value": 43
}, {
  "day": 2,
  "name": "delta2",
  "value": 17
}, {
  "day": 2,
  "name": "delta2",
  "value": 35
}]
var visualization = d3plus.viz()
  .container("#chartContainer")
  .data(data)
  .type({
    "value": "box",
    "mode": "extent" // changes box/whisker from tukey to extent mode
  })
  .id("name")
  .x("day")
  .y("value")
  .time("day")
  .timeline({
        "align":"center",
        "value":true})
  //.format()     // I couldn't find any format for plain data without converting it into time  
  .draw()
```

```html
<script src="//d3plus.org/js/d3.js"></script>
<script src="//d3plus.org/js/d3plus.js"></script>
<div id="chartContainer">
</div>
```